# Installing libraries help

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I am very new to Ubuntu and need some help.

The short version is, I need to install the following libraries:

- OpenGL
- OpenCL
- GLFW3
- GLEW
- Python Libs

Are these libraries installed by default with Ubuntu? If not, how can I go about installing them?

I've looked around and it doesn't seem to be as easy as "sudo apt-get OpenGL", is NPM recommended for installing things like this?

Running 16.04

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "Python libs" you want to install?

Comment: I pulled that list from here: http://www.opengraphiti.com/ . I believe it should be just the default python libraries, and I think python is already installed on ubuntu so I shouldn't need any extra ones

Comment: The `apt-cache search` command is your friend. See `man apt-cache`.

Comment: @Bryce Looking at the website, it looks like you have chosen to install the development version of OpenGraphiti, but this compilation is significantly more involved than the other installation method that uses `pip`, which presumably gives you a less up-to-date version of OpenGraphiti. Any particular reasons why you have to use the development version?

Comment: @edwinksl yes I was looking to install the development version, because I intend to work with some of the latest development tools, as well as possibly add my own. Is installing these libraries going to be involved enough to dissuade someone from using it?